# How to resolve the Error in anaconda start up?

Tags: python, anaconda

Few days ago, Anaconda Navigator used to work fine but now it won't open; I've even reinstalled the navigator but still getting the same issue.

Here is the error message

Navigator Error:

```
An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up
```

Main Error

```
unacceptable character #x0000: special characters are not allowed
  in "C:\Users\home\.continuum\anaconda-client\config.yaml", position 0
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py", line 72, in exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 146, in start_app
    window = run_app(splash)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 65, in run_app
    window = MainWindow(splash=splash)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.api = AnacondaAPI()
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 1518, in AnacondaAPI
    ANACONDA_API = _AnacondaAPI()
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 83, in __init__
    self._client_api = ClientAPI(config=self.config)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 659, in ClientAPI
    CLIENT_API = _ClientAPI(config=config)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.reload_client()
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 322, in reload_client
    url = binstar_client.utils.get_config()['url']
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\config.py", line 249, in get_config
    file_configs = load_file_configs(SEARCH_PATH)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\config.py", line 241, in load_file_configs
    raw_data = collections.OrderedDict(kv for kv in itertools.chain.from_iterable(load_paths))
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\config.py", line 241, in 
    raw_data = collections.OrderedDict(kv for kv in itertools.chain.from_iterable(load_paths))
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\config.py", line 221, in _dir_yaml_loader
    yield filepath, load_config(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\config.py", line 205, in load_config
    data = yaml_load(fd)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\yaml.py", line 12, in yaml_load
    return safe_load(stream)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 162, in safe_load
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 112, in load
    loader = Loader(stream)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\loader.py", line 34, in __init__
    Reader.__init__(self, stream)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\reader.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.determine_encoding()
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\reader.py", line 135, in determine_encoding
    self.update(1)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\reader.py", line 169, in update
    self.check_printable(data)
  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\reader.py", line 143, in check_printable
    raise ReaderError(self.name, position, ord(character),
yaml.reader.ReaderError: unacceptable character #x0000: special characters are not allowed
  in "C:\Users\home\.continuum\anaconda-client\config.yaml", position 0
```

Comment: Can you rename the file `C:\Users\home.continuum\anaconda-client\config.yaml` to something else and check if the navigator starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to github the problem lies with "config.yaml" file in C:\Users\axith.continuum\anaconda-client\config.yaml , rename it to config.old or delete it

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came here for a slightly different error because the last line of my error message was:

```
in "<unicode string>", position ...
```

To fix this, the yaml file needed to be encoded in UTF-8. On Windows you can do that via Save As.. in Notepad.

The answer came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902201/python-yaml-yaml-reader-readererror-unacceptable-character)